# Too much ram usage for relatively small neuronal net in @tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, out-of-memory, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use tensorflow.js to train a model with more then 10.000 input units with the gpu backend.When doing so the memory is filling up my 16GB of ram and it exits the program.I thought that this is not very much, because other people train with at least 640x480 images which would be ~0.3 million input units.Maybe it matters, that I use just one dimension, but anywhere here is my training function:

```
 async function learn() {
        console.log("learn");
        const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

        // Load the binding:
        require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu');  // Use '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu' if running with GPU. / for cpu backend: require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

        const learningRate = 0.00001;
        const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

        // Train a simple model:
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 76800, activation: 'linear', inputShape: [76800]})); //320x240

        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1200, activation: 'relu'}));

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 800, activation: 'relu'}));
        }

        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 60, activation: 'relu'}));

        model.compile({optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

        console.log("in_tensor_sum.length" + in_tensor_sum.length);
        for (var for_ep = 0; for_ep < 100; for_ep++) {
            for (var i = 0; i < in_tensor_sum.length; i++) {

                var pre_xs = [];
                var pre_ys = [];

                pre_xs.push(in_tensor_sum[i]);
                pre_ys.push(out_tensor_sum[i]);


                var xs = tf.tensor(pre_xs);
                var ys = tf.tensor(pre_ys);


                await model.fit(xs, ys, {
                    epochs: 1, batchSize: 1,
                    callbacks: {
                        onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
                            console.log(`Epoch ${for_ep}: loss = ${log.loss}`);
                        },
                        onTrainEnd: async () => {

                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }

     }
```

As you can see I've already tried to reduce the batch size to 1, but that seems to not matter.
Here is the stack trace of the program:

```
cpu backend was already registered. Reusing existing backend
2019-02-10 08:25:46.566395: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-02-10 08:25:46.657945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-02-10 08:25:46.658444: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.759
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 5.93GiB freeMemory: 5.65GiB
2019-02-10 08:25:46.658458: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-02-10 08:25:47.174668: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-02-10 08:25:47.174690: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-02-10 08:25:47.174695: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-02-10 08:25:47.175247: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5419 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
in_tensor_sum.length41
Epoch 1 / 1
2019-02-10 08:26:54.416207: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:122] Allocation of 6400000000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570627: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:267] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 5.96GiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570704: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 3. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 768B in use in bin. 484B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570730: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570756: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570778: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570827: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570867: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570915: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 312.5KiB allocated for chunks. 312.5KiB in use in bin. 312.5KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.570978: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571019: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571038: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571059: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571100: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571121: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571141: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 5.29GiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571186: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:613] Bin for 5.96GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 5.29GiB | Requested Size: 0B | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 256B | Requested Size: 240B | in_use: 1
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571236: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd6000000 of size 256
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571254: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd6000100 of size 1280
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571271: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Free  at 0x7facd6000600 of size 256
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571289: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd6000700 of size 160000
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571306: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd6027800 of size 256
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571323: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd6027900 of size 160000
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Free  at 0x7facd604ea00 of size 256
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571357: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7facd604eb00 of size 256
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Free  at 0x7facd604ec00 of size 5682435072
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571390: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:638]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 3 Chunks of size 256 totalling 768B
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571428: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571448: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 2 Chunks of size 160000 totalling 312.5KiB
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571467: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:645] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 314.5KiB
2019-02-10 08:27:06.571491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:647] Stats: 
Limit:                  5682757632
InUse:                      322048
MaxInUse:                   322560
NumAllocs:                      10
MaxAllocSize:               160000

2019-02-10 08:27:06.571523: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] *___________________________________________________________________________________________________
(node:2186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid TF_Status: 13
Message: Dst tensor is not initialized.
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.getInputTensorIds (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:146:38)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.executeSingleOutput (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:186:73)
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.reshape (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu/dist/nodejs_kernel_backend.js:927:21)
    at environment_1.ENV.engine.runKernel.$x (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:199:83)
    at /home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:129:26
    at Engine.scopedRun (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:101:23)
    at Engine.runKernel (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/engine.js:127:14)
    at reshape_ (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:199:37)
    at Object.reshape (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:23:29)
    at Variable.Tensor.reshape (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor.js:302:26)
(node:2186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2186) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

EDIT:
The filling up of ram happens here (filling my 16GB RAM before exit):

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 76800, activation: 'linear', inputShape: [76800]})); //320x240
```

So I don't get even to model.compile(....);

EDIT 2:
OK, when I create just an empty model with the code below:

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu');

var learningRate = 0.00005;//0.0005
learn_start(learningRate);

async function learn_start(rate) {
    console.log("learn");

    var learningRate = rate;
    var optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

    // Train a simple model:
    var model = tf.sequential();

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 78600, activation: 'linear', inputShape: [78600]})); //320x240 
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1200, activation: 'relu'}));        
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 800, activation: 'relu'}));
    }  
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 60, activation: 'relu'}));

    model.compile({optimizer: optimizer, loss: 'meanSquaredError'});   
}
```

I get the following error:

```
(node:14684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 6177960000
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getArrayFromDType (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/util.js:262:18)
    at new TensorBuffer (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tensor.js:67:28)
    at buffer (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:445:12)
    at truncatedNormal_ (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/array_ops.js:107:15)
    at Object.truncatedNormal (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/ops/operation.js:23:29)
    at GlorotNormal.VarianceScaling.apply (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/initializers.js:260:32)
    at Dense.Layer.addWeight (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/topology.js:576:37)
    at Dense.build (/home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/layers/core.js:131:32)
    at /home/test/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/topology.js:410:23
(node:14684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14684) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: How can the ram memory consumption can happen prior to declaring your model ? Unless there are other processings on GPU prior to the declaration of the first layer

Comment: I don't know.It happens while running model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 76800, activation: 'linear', inputShape: [76800]});

Comment: What happens when you lower the size of the dimension ?

Comment: Looking at the error, it has nothing to do with the ram memory consumption. There are another issue prior to declaring your model. Looking at the error, there seems to be a dimension matching issue. Could you please update your question with the shape of the data passed in to your model ?

Comment: It works when I reduce the units to 4.800 and input shape to 38.000 , but then it is not anymore fully connected,right?

Comment: It means that your previous error was a dimensionality issue. The shape of your data is different of the inputShape

Comment: The two questions are unrelated. I will suggest to you to post the second error in another thread and put the link here in comments. As for the answer of the first question, find my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You are not disposing any of your tensors. Each iteration new tensors are created and kept in memory unless you dispose them using .dispose () or use them inside tf.tidy(). Try tf.memory() to get an overview of how many tensors exist.

Comment: As I edited, the ram consumption already starts on adding the input layer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, your issue is not a ram memory consumption as indicated in your question. You're rather facing a dimension matching issue.

The inputShape of your model should match the shape of the data passed in to the `model.predict` function.